# How do I reuse a previous migration's up or down methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I had created my own User class and authentication from scratch but have recently
decided to scrap it and start over using the Devise gem.
So before I leverage the Devise migrations I need to create a migration
to kill off my User table. "Easy", I thought, "I'll just use the down method of
the migration that created my User table". But I can't for the life of me
work out how to reference that from a new migration.
Thoughts?

Comment: your migration class codesource can help a lot here

Answer (score 0):

If your user migration has anything outside of just dropping the user table I'm not too sure, but you can edit devise's migration and add the force = true option.

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table(:users, :force => true) do |t|
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

This will make it so that if your user table exists, it'll be dropped before hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can just manually drop it:

```
class DropUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    drop_table :users
  end
  def self.down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```